# Caching data from SQL Server in .net vs Session regarding performance

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am currently using .Net 4.5, and code first...all the bells and whistles.

Now I need to do a quick pull pf data from an old SQL Server that's really slow.

I thought to create a session in `Session_start` to pull the data once and for all in a session.

Does `Session_Start` run every time a session is called? If yes, I could only allow a pull of data if session is null.

As for the `Cache` object, does it really give me any real advantage to a session regarding performance?

Comment: You could also use the `Cache` which is available through the complete application lifetime and shared across all sessions if the data never changes anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks alot please reload question

Comment: @Pinch it depends on scope. For `Session` each individual browser session will cause your SQL to run. With `Cache` you can share that same result set between all browser sessions. If the query is unique to a user then using `Session` should be fine. If it's generic for all users then use `Cache` as it can better manage it's storage over time.

Comment: Is this a asp.net?  Exactly what is Session_Start.  Do you mean Session_OnStart?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sessions are PER USER!!!  if you have 200+ concurrent  users browsing  you will experience heavy dropping of Sessions you will need to Store the Session to SQL which will drop 25% performance than memory
2. Cache is common for all users
3. Note that if you use Application will work only for Single Server Applications not working in WebFarms

I will use this as service (Azure have 2 options) and I will save my machines memory...
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/

Note that Cache is also RAM consuming...ORM you can calculate  DATA SIZE == RAM - 20%( fromRAM) you will lose 20% from the RAM

Here very nice article with source code

SQL Cache Dependency with SQL Server, LINQ and ASP.NET 3.5 http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=263

Important (from the article ) GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO "TESTSERVER\ASPNET"

C#

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) { SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pubsConnectionString"].ConnectionString); }

The following code also stops the listener:

protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) { SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pubsConnectionString"].ConnectionString); }

Comment: I will use this as service (Aure have 2 options) and I will save my machines memory... http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/

Note that Cache is also RAM consuming...ORM you can calculate DATA SIZE == RAM - 20%( fromRAM) you will lose 20% from the RAM